# My unity urp rim light shader makes a game object split into two parts

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, urp

I'm very new to urp shader scripting and there'll be my mistake, but i can't figure it out alone..

I want to make a simple rim light shader, but my code always make game objects like this.
[image]

What am I missing??.... I'll be grateful for your help.

This is my HLSL shader code

```
    Properties
    {
        _BaseMap ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags{"RenderType" = "Transparent" "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline"}

        Pass{
Name "Warpped Diffuse"
Tags{"LightMode" = "UniversalForward"}

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex Vertex
            #pragma fragment Fragment
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Lighting.hlsl"
            struct appdata{
                float4 positionOS : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float3 normalOS : NORMAL;
            };

            struct v2f{
                float4 positionHCS : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float3 normalWS : TEXCOORD1;
                float3 positionWS : TEXCOORD2;
            };

            TEXTURE2D(_BaseMap);
            SAMPLER(sampler_BaseMap);

            CBUFFER_START(UnityPerMaterial)
            float4 _BaseMap_ST;
            CBUFFER_END

            v2f Vertex(appdata input){
                v2f o;
                o.positionHCS = TransformObjectToHClip(input.positionOS.xyz);
                o.positionWS = GetVertexPositionInputs(input.positionOS).positionWS;
                o.normalWS = GetVertexNormalInputs(input.normalOS).normalWS;
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(input.uv, _BaseMap);
                return o;
            }

            float4 Fragment(v2f input) : SV_Target {
                float normalizedNormal = normalize(input.normalWS);
                float3 viewDir = GetWorldSpaceNormalizeViewDir(input.positionWS);
                float ndotv = saturate(dot(normalizedNormal,  viewDir));

                return ndotv;
            }

            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
```

What I tried :
Writing simple HLSL rim light shader code using view direction and normal vector from world space

What I expected :
rim light effect

Result :
game object that is split to half ???